# save outlier removed data back to new csv file

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, outliers

I have a pandas dataframe and I am experimenting with [sci-kit learn Novelty and Outlier Detection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html). I am trying figure out how to save my `good` dataset back to new a new CSV file after the outlier detector flags outliers.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import LocalOutlierFactor

df = pd.read_csv('./ILCplusDAT.csv')
df = df.fillna(method = 'ffill').fillna(method = 'bfill')

npower_pid = df[['power','pid']].to_numpy()
```

And using the sci kit learn feature where visually to me the results look good only using 2 of the columns `power & pid` of the original df:

```
ax = plt.figure(figsize=(25,8))

lof = LocalOutlierFactor(n_neighbors=20, contamination=0.005)
good = lof.fit_predict(npower_pid) == 1
plt.scatter(npower_pid[good, 0], npower_pid[good, 1], s=2, label="Good", color="#4CAF50")
plt.scatter(npower_pid[~good, 0], npower_pid[~good, 1], s=8, label="Bad", color="#F44336")
plt.legend();
```

Which creates an interesting plot that I would love to save a "filtered" original data frame of `"BAD"` data removed. Any tips greatly appreciated...hopefully this makes sense. The original data frame is 3 columns but the filtered data as shown in the plot below is only 2 of those columns. Can I still filter the original dataframe based on the output shown in this plot?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to filter `df` using your array, `good`:

```
# you can filter df using bool masking in .loc[...]
df.loc[good == True]

# or...
df.loc[good == False]

# ***NOTE: if you've altered the index in df you may have unexpected results.
# convert `good` into a `pd.Series` with the same index as `df`
s = pd.Series(good, index=df.index, name="is_outlier")

# ... join with df
df = df.join(s)

# then filter to True
df.loc[df.is_outlier == True]

# or False
df.loc[df.is_outlier == False]
```

Comment: In my code `good` is an array....can I put this back into a pandas a column? If I print it looks like this below sorry not a lot of wisdom here.

Comment: `array([ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True])`

Comment: @bbartling -- yes. But I'd confirm that it doesn't mess with your index. May be safer to convert to a series first then join on index --> `s = pd.Series(good, index=df.index, name="is_outlier")` --> `df.join(s)`

Comment: Yeah that works no errors if I use that and `df = df.join(s)`

Comment: `is_outlier` comes into the original df as its own column. So then I think I just need to filter it based on when that column is True

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ian Thompson

My code for what its worth...

```
s = pd.Series(good, index=df.index, name="is_outlier")
df = df.join(s)

# df2 is filtered to remove BAD data
df2 = df[(df['is_outlier']==True)]
df2 = df2[['pid','power','dat']]
df2.to_csv('./filteredILCdata.csv')
```